# How can i fill missing faces?

Tags: faces

I have been currently modelling a dragon for my portfolio but I have come to a problem because of the mirror modifier. How can I solve this?[image: missing faces]

Comment: Maybe use a boolean object in order to fill the holes?

Answer (score 0):

Select the vertices and use "F" (fill face command). Another option is "M" (merge vertices). If you go the fill face route you'll also want to apply Mesh>Normals>Recalculate Outside.